# Ideas with processing OSM data graph for output simple city/village nodes with edges between them

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, path-finding, openstreetmap

[image: Input Graph and Output Graph after processing]

The image above shows 3 elements:

- Input Graph - created from OSM data for one country.
- Procedure - transforms Input Graph to Output graph
- Output Graph - Much simpler version of the input Graph without detailed nodes on each roads. It contains only cities/villages nodes and edges that are calculated based on Input Graph roads.

I would like to create Output Graph from Input Graph. In other words, I need a graph that let me quickly calculate the answer to this question: If I start from city 3 and drive to city 7, which city/villages will I be passing?
In this example, the answers are:

- You will be passing cities/villages: 5, 6, 7
- You will be passing cities/villages: 2, 4, 6, 7
- You will be passing cities/villages: 5, 4, 6, 7

The city/village nodes are retrieved from an OSM file. The Output Graph edges should have weights calculated based on the input graph edges. The weight is the distance (in meters) from one node to the next.

In the original OSM data file (and in Input Graph), nodes that describe a city or a village aren't connected with edges from roads. What I see I have to process this graph fetch only nodes representing cities and villages and then try to match (based on distances from city/village node to road nodes) and make some shortcuts roads that connect only cities/village nodes.

My questions are:

- Has this already been done? I don't want to duplicate somebodys work.
- how would you create the Output Graph?

Answer (score 1):

You could find a path based on routing algorithms. There are several software realizations for this, like osmand.
Then, in the OSM data, do not look for nodes representing a city, but look instead for administrative boundaries (polygons) of cities.
At this point, with a classical geometry algorithm, you can compute the list of intersections between the route and the administrative boundaries.

This approach solves your problem, but does not compute a simplified graph as an intermdiate step. As such, it is more computer intensive for each request.

I'm afraid that with a graph made of roads, there is a huge number of different paths between two points, going through possibly all cities in the data, in various orders. So you need some optimization criterion to choose a small number of paths (short distance, short travel time, no toll, scenic roads, etc.). Which leads to the need for some routing algorithm, which leads to the above solution...